# Does Microsoft include automatic .NET version checks when launching an application?`

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, version, environment

I recently included a check for the correct .NET version when launching an application I created. Very simple:

```
if (Environment.Version.Major < 4)
{
    //Alert user, exit program
}
```

However, I noticed when I ran a different .NET application I wrote (that didn't have the check) on a computer without the necessary .NET version, there was an alert telling me I couldn't run the app. Do applications written in VS2012 automatically include such a check or should I be writing one in?

Answer (score 1):

.NET will only run if the version that your application is targetting is installed.  If you wrote the app and targetted `.NET 4.0` for example, and the machine does not have 4.0 installed, the app won't start at all, so the check using *Environment.Version* is pretty much redundant.

To be able to truly determine if and which version of .NET is installed without a dependency on .NET (chicken and egg problem), you need to write the detection app/bits in a different language, like C++, see this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785) for info on what to look for in the registry (one of the few ways to verify which version of .NET is installed), the keys should be located in **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\**

Answer (score 0):

Your check won't work, because the program simply won't launch, but try this in your `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Then a nice popup will display showing the user the issue.

Comment: Okay. One follow-up question: Will the popup still work if, say, the user just ran the .exe from the debug folder and didn't install the program?

Comment: Sure, the only time it won't work is if they don't have .net installed at all. In that case you need a solution such as @Jason proposed in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. If you don't have correct version of .NET installer user will see only "app has stopped working" message.

What you may want to do is .NET app bootstrapper.